# how can I solve a redundant symbolic system in matlab?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, equation-solving, equations

let

```
    n0 =

 nx*cos(a) + nz*cos(b)*sin(a) + ny*sin(a)*sin(b)
                           ny*cos(b) - nz*sin(b)
 nz*cos(a)*cos(b) - nx*sin(a) + ny*cos(a)*sin(b)
```

in a and b,with the ns fixed (but of course,not assigned) values.
if I do

```
[a,b]=solve(n0-[1 0 0]',a,b,'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints',true)
```

i get

```
    Error using solve>assignOutputs (line 257)
3 variables does not match 2 outputs.

    Error in solve (line 193)
varargout = assignOutputs(nargout,sol,sym(vars));
```

then I wonder ''3 variables''?
Then I try

```
>> [a,b,c]=solve(n0-[1 0 0]',a,b,'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints',true)
```

that's the response

```
a =

cos(a)/(cos(a)^2 + sin(a)^2)


b =

(sin(a)*sin(b))/((cos(a)^2 + sin(a)^2)*(cos(b)^2 + sin(b)^2))


c =

(cos(b)*sin(a))/((cos(a)^2 + sin(a)^2)*(cos(b)^2 + sin(b)^2))
```

what is it doing? what's in c? I suppose he's solving with respect to nx ny nz,but why?every time I try to solve a problem with n+k equation in n variables I get strange errors,even if the rank of the system is just n.

that means even a=2 b=3 a+b=5 gives me problems.
how can I fix that?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem, please provide a complete example including all initialisations which allows to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also cannot replicate the "Error in solve" error. What version of Matlab are you using? Also, I think some of the error message is missing – always list the entire error message. In any case, R2013a, `solve` does not find any solutions. Mathematica 9's `Solve` also does not find any.

I suspect why @DanielR and I can't exactly reduce your issue in the second case is that you may have a mistake in one of your lines above – it should be:

```
[a,b,c] = solve(n0-[1 0 0]','IgnoreAnalyticConstraints',true)
```

that produces

```
a =

cos(a)/(cos(a)^2 + sin(a)^2)


b =

(sin(a)*sin(b))/((cos(a)^2 + sin(a)^2)*(cos(b)^2 + sin(b)^2))


c =

(cos(b)*sin(a))/((cos(a)^2 + sin(a)^2)*(cos(b)^2 + sin(b)^2))
```

What are the outputs `a`, `b`, and `c` (these simplify to `cos(a)`, `sin(a)*sin(b)`, and `sin(a)*cos(b)`, by the way)? A big hint is that all of the solutions are in terms of your original variables `a` and `b`, but not `nx`, `ny`, or `nz`. When you don't specify which variables to solve for `solve` picks them. If you instead return the solutions in structure form, the nature of the output is made clear:

```
s = solve(n0-[1 0 0]','IgnoreAnalyticConstraints',true)

s = 

    nx: [1x1 sym]
    ny: [1x1 sym]
    nz: [1x1 sym]
```

But I think that you probably want to solve for `a` and `b` as a function of `nx`, `ny`, and `nz`, not the other way around. You're not correct about using `solve` to find solutions to overdetermined systems. Even when you have more equations then unknowns this is not always possible with nonlinear equations. If you can introduce some [`assumptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumptions.html) or even additional equations or specify numerical values for any of the `nx`, `ny`, or `nz` variables, `solve` may be able to separate and invert the equations.

And you shouldn't really use the term "rank" *except* for linear systems. In the case of the linear system example that you gave `solve` works fine:

```
[a,b] = solve([a==2 b==3 a+b==5],a,b)
```

or

```
[a,b] = solve(a==2,b==3,a+b==5,a,b)
```

or

```
[a,b] = solve([1 0;0 1;1 1]*[a;b]==[2;3;5],a,b)
```

returns

```
Warning: 3 equations in 2 variables. 
> In /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/toolbox/symbolic/symbolic/symengine.p>symengine at 56
  In mupadengine.mupadengine>mupadengine.evalin at 97
  In mupadengine.mupadengine>mupadengine.feval at 150
  In solve at 170 

a =

2


b =

3
```